# php form submitting que. and ans. for online exam

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Tough Time in inserting a query.

My form is having 1 question, 4 options with radio button in while loop. Questions and options are fetched from table named paper, I used array for question and answers. Below is the code I used.

```
<form id="form1" action="submit_answer.php" method="post">
<?php
$get_question = mysql_query("select * from paper where test_name='$test_name' ORDER BY RAND()");
$count = 0;
$sr = 1;
if(mysql_num_rows($get_question)==0)
{
    echo "No Questions Found For ".$test_name;
}
else
{
    while($row_question = mysql_fetch_array($get_question))
    {
        $id = $row_question["id"];
        $question = $row_question["question"];
        $option1 = $row_question["option1"];
        $option2 = $row_question["option2"];
        $option3 = $row_question["option3"];
        $option4 = $row_question["option4"];
        $answer = $row_question["answer"];

        echo '<div class="question_box">
                <p>'.$sr.'. '.$question.'</p>
                <div style="margin:10px 0 0 10px;">

                    <input type="text" value="'.$std.'" name="std" />
                    <input type="text" value="'.$student_name.'" name="student_name" />
                    <input type="text" value="'.$test_name.'" name="test_name" />
                    <input type="text" value="'.$question.'" name="question[]" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="'.$answer.'" name="true_answer[]" />
                    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="given_answer['.$count.']" value="A" />&nbsp;'.$option1.'<br/>
                    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="given_answer['.$count.']" value="B" />&nbsp;'.$option2.'<br/>
                    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="given_answer['.$count.']" value="C" />&nbsp;'.$option3.'<br/>
                    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="given_answer['.$count.']" value="D" />&nbsp;'.$option4.'<br/>
                    <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="answers" name="given_answer['.$count.']" value="NONE" style="display:none;" />
                </div>
        </div>';
        $count++;
        $sr++;
    }
}
?>
    <button class="stdbtn btn_black" style="opacity: 1;" type="button" onclick="submit_exam();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, submit_answer.php page is for submitting all questions and answers with student std, student name, test name, questions and answers. Below is the code I used:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
    echo "<br />";
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";

    mysql_query("insert into student_answer($key) values($value)");

    echo mysql_error();
}
```

It does insert std of the student but not the rest of the values and gives me error.

```
**Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'**
```

Table fields are:

```
+------++--------------++-----------++----------++--------------+
| std  || student_name || test_name || question || given_answer |
+------++--------------++-----------++----------++--------------+
```

Kindly help me out in above query. Thanks in Advance!! :)

Comment: You might want to examine the actual _contents_ of `$_POST` before just throwing it at the database.  For two reasons: 1) I bet those radio buttons are being submitted as an array, not as individual values, which is causing the error; and 2) This code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  Not only can a user easily get every question right, they can also get whatever they want from your database, including possibly shell access to the server.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: For sure radio buttons are being submitted as `given_answer[NumberX]`, `given_answer[NumberY]`, `given_answer[NumberZ]`, thus, as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL I got my own answer, query will be as per the below:

```
$count = $_POST["count"];    // hidden value under the while loop

for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
   $test_name = $_POST["test_name"];
   $std = $_POST["std"];
   $student_name = $_POST["student_name"];
   $question = $_POST["question"][$i-1];
   $given_answer = $_POST["given_answer"][$i-1];

   mysql_query("insert into student_answer(std,student_name,test_name,question,given_answer) values('$std','$student_name','$test_name','$question','$given_answer')");

    echo mysql_error();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$given_answer` as an array parameter so it is returning an `array` in `$key`. Try to use a hidden parameter count and then insert `$key[$count]`.

Comment: didnt got u.. actuly i want a query to insert all values from form to table. please help me with that....

Comment: use if(is_array($key)) { foreach($key as $key1 => value1){ insert code} else { insert code}

Comment: foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
        if(is_array($key))
        {
            foreach($key as $key[$count] => $value[$count])
            {
                mysql_query("insert into student_answer(*****) values(*******)");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("insert into student_answer(*****) values(*****)");
        }
 }


So what would be the query????

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you buy available online scripts in market as starting point for it. This will save you time, cost and testing efforts.

Below is one of the fine scripts that I worked it and it worked like charm. Using this as base I developed a online testing portal of over 1000 users using computer adaptive test.

http://codecanyon.net/item/online-skills-assessment/9379895

It is a good starting point for people looking to develop Online Exam System